# Salted password hashes

Tags: authentication, hash, passwords, salt

I am trying to create a login system for a web application, but I am stuck on a couple of points. I am storing the password in my database using a sha2-512 hash with a 128 bit random salt.

However I currently have the password posted in plain text to my application using a html form, both when the account is created and when the user logs in. I know this is wrong.

Do I need to hash the password in the client? If so how do I take into account the salt which is currently generated and stored on the database?

NOTE: I am doing this to learn not to use in a production system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashing the password on the client would require the use of the salt on the client. This also exposes your algorithm for very easy hacking on the client side. The best thing to do is to perform this action over SSL (HTTPS) so that the entire transaction is encrypted and the authentication only happens on the server.

I.e.: Your user ID and password are transmitted encrypted from the client. The web server decrypts the data and passes it to your server-side authentication function where you look up the user and associated salt, perform password + salt + hash and compare it to the stored hash for a match. This means that the hash and then salt never need to be transmitted from the server at all.

Answer (score 3):

The best bet is generally just to use SSL.  If you did need to hash on the client side, this is how I'd do it:

1. When you first store the password, hash the password with a stored salt as is commonly done.
2. When someone needs to login, send them the stored salt, along with a second, randomly generated salt.
3. The client will hash the plaintext password with the stored salt, then the random salt and send the hash to the server.
4. The server will hash the stored password with the random used in that request salt and compare.

This is secure because it ensures that the hash being transmitted is unique to the request (it uses a single-request random salt), so a login cannot be faked in the future simply by sending the hash again.  It is not dangerous to send the client their stored salt, as it is assumed that password crackers will have access to the stored salt (if they get access to the db).  Two hashes are required to prevent you from ever having to store the password as plaintext.

Comment: That is not an insecure solution per se if correctly implemented - at least the minor security tradeoffs of exposing the salt and algorithm can be considered acceptable. However, it is rather convoluted and requires some sort of session state handling. It doesn't translate well for stateless services where credentials are typically transmitted in every request. This can be solved using something like a secure login token, but this introduces complexity (and thus, security risks). 
The best approach is hashing on the server and transmitting the credentials via an encrypted connection.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using SSL to transmit the passwords encrypted so that a man-in-the-middle can't intercept the packets and read off what ever credential is being sent.  Even if you pre-hash the password in the client, a man-in-the-middle can still just use that value to fake identity.

What really concerns me, though, is the use of SHA-512.  A lot of people use cryptographic hashes for password storage, but popular opinion misses a very important point:  These hashes were *designed* to be *fast*.  That is, one of the *requirements* to become an SHA (or similar) hash is to be able to quickly hash large documents on embedded hardware.

This is the exact opposite of what you want for password storage, as it allows specialized routines on high performance GPUs to brute force passwords at a surprising and scary speed!

This is why some purpose built password storage hashes have been developed.  The one I have been using is [Bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), which is slow enough to keep out brute force attacks, adjustable to couneract faster hardware in the future, and has the added bonus of handling the salting for you.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be using SSL on any page where you are transmitting passwords. If you try to encrypt them on the client side it will be in javascript and very easily reverse-engineerable.

Comment: The purpose of a hash is that it is not reversible.

Comment: @ZackBloom you can still implement bidirectional encryption solely for transmitting the password from client to server (where it is hashed and stored)

Comment: However, someone could easily disable the javascript and thus disable the client side hashing. This would mean that the password would be sent over clear text.

Comment: Also, as mentioned above, the salt would need to be exposed on the client side and thus the algorithm used to hash the passwords would be weakened.

Comment: @MatthewPK As I said, that's unnecessary, as hashes are already not feasible to reverse.

Comment: @moshjeier If you are hashing client-side, you are using AJAX to submit the form.  Disabling javascript would prevent anything from being sent.  You would actually need to hash/salt the password twice, see my response.

Comment: @ZackBloom I think you're missing our point here: if your client-side hashing algorithm is exposed to the user (via the input and the ouput) then there is no point hashing on the client side at all. Let the hash be done securely on the server.

Comment: @MatthewPK The purpose of the hash is to be cryptographically unfeasible to reverse, such that with the hash, you cannot reconstruct the plaintext.  Knowing how the hash is computed is not an issue.  Hashing on the client side is exactly as secure as hashing on the server.  The danger hashing on the client side is that someone intercepting the transmission could get the hash and use it to authenticate their own requests, just as if you transmitted the password plaintext.  You could however use a two-fold hashing, see my answer for more details.